# Implementing a downtime on a resource that waits for the resource to finish its task before delaying it

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to represent a machine that works for a x amount of time before warning the operator that the oil tank needs to be refilled. Have in mind that the machine doesn't stop as soon as it send the warning message out. That way, the operator will wait until the machine stops any activity it had already started, and once it's done, he'll stop the machine and fill the tank.

In order to represent this process I'm using a Station block from the Material Handling library, that seizes a resource from a resource pool block, to which a downtime block is applied.

Is there a way to make the downtime block wait until the machine stops before performing the maintenance?

I also want to associate a resource pool representative of the operator to the downtime block, so that the operator is busy during the downtime, since he's the responsible for filling the tank. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make the downtime block wait until the machine stops before performing the maintenance?

Yes, explore how Priorities work. Give your machine task a *higher* priority than the downtime task and ensure that the downtime block does *not* preempt other tasks:
[image]

> I also want to associate a resource pool representative of the operator to the downtime block, so that the operator is busy during the downtime, since he's the responsible for filling the tank. Can I do that?

Yes, set the task type to "go to flowchart" and use a custom flow chart to seize from a resource pool (again, check the help on how to set this up in detail):
[image]

Comment: @FranciscoMarques please mark the reply as "useful" (up arrow next to the reply) so others will find it easier in the future. Ensure to understand https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote :)